# How to get first row of group in summarise-function within dbplyr-query

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

I want to select the first row of a grouped dataset within a `dbplyr` query. For this I want to use to `summarise` function.
In a normal dplyr pipeline this works without any problems:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  arrange(cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(test = head(mpg, 1))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl  test
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  22.8
2     6  21  
3     8  18.7
```

Now I want to transfer this principle to the dbplyr query:

```
# Creating a simple test connection
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
# Inserting test table
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)


con %>% 
  tbl("mtcars") %>% 
  arrange(cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(test = head(cyl, 1)) %>% 
  collect()

Error in `collect()`:
! Failed to collect lazy table.
Caused by error:
! no such function: head
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

However, the `head()`-function cannot be translated using dbplyr in a SQL-statement and therefore an error appears.
Can anyone help me find an alternative to get the first element of a grouped dataset within the `dbplyr`-query?
(Likewise, I also need a function to get the **last** element of the grouped record).

Comment: Just a guess, there is a `first` function in dplyr, instead of `head`, did you try?

Comment: Also, maybe not relevant, it is `head(mpg`, and in dbplyr it is `head(cyl`

Comment: @zx8754 seems like you're missing brackets?

Comment: @Mark I think it is typo, in dplyr they are getting head of mpg and dbplyr they are getting head of cyl.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly why it is not possible just to use dplyr syntax in dbplyr directly, maybe see this GitHub issue for more info: [first() doesn't work in summaries](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/129)

But here is an alternative that works for both:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  arrange(cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(First = first(mpg), Last = last(mpg)) %>% 
  select(cyl, First, Last) %>% 
  distinct()

con %>% 
  tbl("mtcars") %>% 
  arrange(cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(First = first(mpg), Last = last(mpg)) %>% 
  select(cyl, First, Last) %>% 
  distinct()

# # Source:     SQL [3 x 3]
# # Database:   sqlite 3.41.2 []
# # Groups:     cyl
# # Ordered by: cyl
#     cyl First  Last
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  22.8  21.4
# 2     6  21    19.7
# 3     8  18.7  15
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `row_number()` in a `filter`:

```r
con %>%
  tbl("mtcars") %>%
  arrange(cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1L) %>%
  collect()
# Warning: ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT
# ℹ Do you need to move arrange() later in the pipeline or use window_order() instead?
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 2  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
# 3  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
```

FYI, this fails without `arrange` because SQL (at least some servers?) require an `ORDER BY` argument in its `OVER` clause. While `arrange(cyl) %>% group_by(cyl)` otherwise seems odd, it provides a mechanism that preserves the existing (natural) sort of the table (otherwise we could `arrange` by something else, if it were meaningful to you).

```r
con %>%
  tbl("mtcars") %>%
  arrange(cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1L) %>%
  show_query()
# Warning: ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT
# ℹ Do you need to move arrange() later in the pipeline or use window_order() instead?
# <SQL>
# SELECT
#   "mpg",
#   "cyl",
#   "disp",
#   "hp",
#   "drat",
#   "wt",
#   "qsec",
#   "vs",
#   "am",
#   "gear",
#   "carb"
# FROM (
#   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "cyl" ORDER BY "cyl") AS "q03"
#   FROM "mtcars"
# ) "q01"
# WHERE ("q03" = 1)
```

(Feel free to add any `select(..)` you need.)

Comment: `dbplyr::window_order()` is another option that does not produce the warning.